# Right Double Quotes (”) not Being Read Correctly by BufferedReader or FileReader

Tags: java, unicode, stream, ascii

I've written a Java program that reads from a text file and removes all the line breaks and double spaces. It's been working as expected until recently it had to read a text file with a ” character in it. I don't know why but it reads the ” character as a strange Asian character I don't recognize.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Place a ” character in the input.txt
2. Run the program

**Expected Results:**

The ” character is placed in the input.txt

**Actual Results**

A weird character code is placed in the input.txt

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedFlavorException{

        String line = null;
        String fileName = "Input.txt";

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String output = "";

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            output += (line + "\n");
        }   


        output = output.replaceAll("-\n", "");
        output = output.replaceAll("\n", " ");
        output = output.replaceAll("  ", " ");

        System.out.println(output);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        bufferedWriter.write(output);

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();

    }
}
```

I can use println to print the ” character to System.out, I can even cast it from character to string without it being changed to another character. I suspect either the bufferedReader/Writer or the fileReader/Writer is corrupting the ” character, although I can't find anything about character limitations in the documentation. Has anyone run into this problem before? Really hoping it's happening because of something incredibly obvious and I'm just dumb.

**Edit:** I'm using Windows 10 and the file is using the UTF-8 Charset

Comment: Which charset encoding is the file using?

Comment: @MickMnemonic According to Notepad++ it's UTF-8

Comment: You don't say which OS you're on. If it's Windows likely the default character set is ISO-8859-1, so the UTF-8 input is being interpreted incorrectly.  Use an explicit `InputStreamReader` that specifies UTF-8 and wrap it around a `FileInputStream`

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm using windows 10 and the file is encoded with UTF-8. I'll try using an inputStreamReader instead.

Comment: Or [`Files.newBufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-) which always uses `UTF-8` when no charset has been specified.

Comment: @Holger that fixed it, the problem was because of the character encoding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Holger, @MickMnemonic, and @Jim helped find a solution in the comments. I'm putting my solution here in case anyone comes across this question later.

The problem was inconsistent charset encodings, the file was UTF-8 and the BufferedReader and BufferedWriter weren't reading it as such. Creating the reader and writer with Files.newBufferedReader() and Files.newBufferedWriter() creates a BufferedReader and BufferedWriter that read and write in UTF-8.